# Github contribution bug

Tags: git, github

In the last two days, I made a couple of contributions in my repo.
But those contributions are not showing in my GitHub contributions chart.

Also in a repo, there is a wired thing going on...my image on the commit is not there.

[image: contributions]

[image: commits]

Comment: Please show `git status` and `git remote show origin`.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+count+contribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, the email is key.

Your commits are done with the right user.name, but the user.email must be off, meaning not the one used by your GitHub account.

Go to your repo folder and type:

```
cd /path/to/my/local/repo
git config user.email
```

Make sure the email is the correct one (the one used in your GitHub account page)

As explained in "[Personalizing your profile](https://help.github.com/articles/personalizing-your-profile/)", the email is what allows the **[Gravatar service](https://en.gravatar.com/)** to associate your user profile picture.

Comment: yes, I figured out the solution...The email address in my git.config file was wrong.

Comment: @SIDDHARTHVARSHNEY Exactly. If you want to modify the email of your past commits: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/